# access WebControls markable properties in constructor asp net

Tags: asp.net, custom-server-controls

Here is my custom control.It inherits [Height] property from WebControl class.I want to access it in constructor for calculating other properties.But its value is always 0.Any idea?

```
    public class MyControl : WebControl, IScriptControl
{

    public MyControl()
    {
       AnotherProperty = Calculate(Height);
       .......
    }
```

my aspx

```
       <hp:MyControl   Height = "31px" .... />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Markup values are not available in your control's constructor but they are available from within your control's OnInit event.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    // has value even before the base OnInit() method in called
    var height = base.Height;

    base.OnInit(e);
}
```

Comment: but how can I access Height in  GetScriptDescriptors() method?

Comment: do you mean I must save Height in other variable?  this.U  = base.Height;

Comment: I am not completely following what you are trying to do and don't have any familiarity with the `IScriptControl` interface.

Comment: Not sure saving it in a different variable changes things. Referencing it off of the "base" object is more a convention / best practice than anything else. If you don't have a local member named Height, you don't have to differentiate between them.

It might be helpful to include more source code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

As @andleer said markup has not been read yet in control's constructor, therefore any property values that are specified in markup are not available in constructor. Calculate another property on demand when it is about to be used and make sure that you not use before OnInit:

```
private int fAnotherPropertyCalculated = false;
private int fAnotherProperty;
public int AnotherProperty
{
  get 
  {
    if (!fAnotherPropertyCalculated)
    {
       fAnotherProperty = Calculate(Height);
       fAnotherPropertyCalculated = true;
    }
    return fAnotherProperty;
  }
}
```