# WebControl's constructor does not have correct attribute value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webcontrol

I want the constructor of my `WebControl` to be able to access the value of `IsSpecial` (from the HTML). However, it's always `false`. I *assume* that it's `false` in the constructor because it doesn't read the value until after the constructor method is over. Is there a way to have it so it knows the correct value of `IsSpecial` in the constructor?

C#:

```
[DefaultProperty("Text")]
[ToolboxData("<{0}:WebControlExample runat=server></{0}:WebControlExample>")]
public class WebControlExample: WebControl, INamingContainer
{
    private readonly int[] goodies;

    public WebControlExample()
    {
        if (this.isSpecial)
        {
            goodies = new int[24];
        }
        else
        {
            //always reaches here
            goodies = new int[48];
        }
    }

    private bool isSpecial= false;
    public bool IsSpecial
    {
        set
        {
            this.isSpecial= value;
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<xyz:WebControlExamplerunat="server" id="webControlExample" IsSpecial="true" />
```

Comment: Can you run the code in the setter for `IsSpecial` instead?

Comment: @DStanley No because I update a `private readonly` variable in the constructor based on the setting. Updated the question.

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420320/access-webcontrols-markable-properties-in-constructor-asp-net

Comment: @RickS That won't work because of my `readonly` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a great solution, but if you *have* to have a readonly array, you could have *two* readonly arrays and wrap them in an accessor:

```
[DefaultProperty("Text")]
[ToolboxData("<{0}:WebControlExample runat=server></{0}:WebControlExample>")]
public class WebControlExample: WebControl, INamingContainer
{
    private readonly int[] goodies = new int[48];
    private readonly int[] goodiesSpecial = new int[24];

    private bool isSpecial= false;
    public bool IsSpecial
    {
        set
        {
            this.isSpecial= value;
        }
    }

    private int[] Goodies
    {
         get {return isSpecial ? goodiesSpecial : goodies;}
    }
}
```

But you haven't stated 1. Why you need two different-sized arrays or 2. What you're doing with them.

Comment: This is actually a very plausible solution. If there many different possible sizes for `goodies`, then this wouldn't be reasonable. It works for my case though.

Answer (score 1):

The value entered in the markup for the `IsSpecial` property won't have been assigned to the property until after the constructor is run. Think about it,.. you're expecting code equivalent to the following:

```
WebControlExample webControlExample = null;
webControlExample.IsSpecial = true;
webControlExample = new WebControlExample();
```

What's actually happening (simplified!) is:

```
WebControlExample webControlExample = null;
webControlExample = new WebControlExample();
webControlExample.IsSpecial = true;
```

There is no way to affect this for the constructor, and you probably shouldn't be doing much of anything in the constructor for a WebControl anyway.

Comment: I figured this was the case, but is there no work around? Is there a way I can pass a parameter to the constructor from the HTML side?

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc, I've never seen it done and aren't familiar with any way of writing custom controls that the asp.net compiler will call a custom ctor on, I'm afraid. Is there a reason the work has to be done in the ctor and can't be done at another stage of the controls lifecycle?

Comment: The web control does a lot of work and the `readonly` variable must stay `readonly`. This means I cannot `extend` either. I want to make a small variation on the web control based on this one parameter. I could just make a whole new class and move common code to a shared class, but I thought that was way too much work for something that I believe was a small change.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc Why does it have to be `readonly` if it's `private`?  Are you afraid other code is going to reassign the array?